# Загрузка класса из библиотеки

Tags: java

Если у меня один и тот же класс содержат несколько джарников, могу ли я насильно в коде указать, что я хочу загрузить этот класс из конкретного джарника?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря что, вы подразумеваете под "один и тот же класс":

1. у них одинаковое имя, но разные package - класс всегда грузится по полному имени класса (учитывая имя пакета), - тут все ясно;
2. у них одинаковое имя и одинаковый package - загрузится тот, который первым будет найден, а первым будет найден тот, который первым попадает в classpath (скорее за все, в порядке подключения jar файлов)

**UPDATE**: полезный линк - [Управление переменной classpath с помощью JWhich](http://www.javable.com/javaworld/tips/105_tt/).

Comment: Одинаковое имя и одинаковый package, конечно.